# Area of largest triangle under $y=e^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I came across this question and I'm unsure how to solve it. The question wasn't originally in English, and English isn't my first language so please excuse any terminology/grammar mistakes.

> A tangent is drawn through the point P on the curve $y=e^{-x}$. The tangent together with the positive $y$-axis and a horizontal line that goes through P cuts a triangle. Find the biggest possible value of the triangle's area.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to add a picture.

The placement of P is very important to this question, but I can't figure out where its most logical placement would be.

I know I can find the equation of the tangent by $y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ but I'm unsure how to go from there.

Comment: If you can post a link to the diagram, I'll post the diagram for you.

Comment: Is the point P restricted to the positive x-axis?

Comment: I see you have put the tag "algebra-precalculus" on this problem. Does that mean that you expect a solution which does not require any calculus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(\alpha, e^{-\alpha})$ be the point then the tangent

$y-e^{-\alpha}=-e^{-\alpha}(x-\alpha)$

meets Y-axis at $A(0,e^{-\alpha}(\alpha +1))$. The horizontal line through $P$ meets Y-axis at $B(0,e^{-\alpha})$.

The area of triangle $PAB$ is

$S(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2} (\alpha)^2 e^{-\alpha}$

Use derivatives to see that $\alpha= 0, 2$ are the stationary points. Also the second derivative $S''(2)<0$, so $S_{max}=2/e^2$

Comment: The correct formula for the area is $S(\alpha)=\frac12\alpha^{\color{red}2}e^{-\alpha}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3600267).

Comment: Yes I missed one $\alpha$. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent will intersect the $y$-axis at the point 
$$
y-f(x_P)=[f'(x_P)(x-x_P)]_{x=0}=-f'(x_P)x_P.
$$
Thus the area of the triangle in question reads:
$$
A(x_P)=\frac{|f'(x_P)x_P^2|}2.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the function is $f'(x)=-e^{-x}$

Let's say the point $P$ had the co-ordinates $(p, e^{-p}$

Then the tangent line at that point would be provided by:

$\dfrac{y-e^{-p}}{x-p}=-e^{-p} \implies y=-xe^{-p}+e^{-p}(p+1)$

We're talking about a positive y-axis so the lowest that line can go is the origin.

Turns out that that point satisfies the positive $y$ condition and maximizes both base and height of the triangle. So that would be when this happens:

$0=0 \cdot e^{-p}+e^{-p}(p+1)$

$e^{-p}(p+1)=0$

$p=-1$ or positive infinity. If you check that curve it tends to $0$ for bigger values of $x$. But that's not the point for now.

$P=(-1, e)$

There's the strategic point.